# Create Unique Account number for every user that registers to the system using Woocommerce My account page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to provide a unique account number to every new user that registers into our woocommerce store so for that i tried to do update_user_meta and this is the code that i tried but no go so please assist

```
add_action('user_register', 'vmart_add_account_number', 10, 1);

function vmart_add_account_number($user_id)
{
    $accountnumber = 1;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'account_number', $accountnumber);
}
```

I am not able to create the custom field and only after that I can think of making it unique so please assist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

You can used `woocommerce_created_customer` hook to update user meta after user registration.

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'vmart_add_account_number');
function vmart_add_account_number($user_id)
{
    $accountnumber = rand(pow(10, 4-1), pow(10, 4)-1).$user_id;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'account_number', $accountnumber);
}
```

For **unique account number** create random  x digit number and add userID at last for unique.Check bellow code this create 4 digit random number + UserID

```
$accountnumber = rand(pow(10, 4-1), pow(10, 4)-1).$user_id;
```

Comment: @DhavalChheda  You're most welcome. I'm glad it helped

Comment: I was using a plugin called refer a friend and there I saw this hook ( after i posted the question ) and then was planning on how to use it but you answered it and saved my headache